# Double Summation - am I interpreting this assignment correctly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm working on an assignment that says

$\sum_{i=2}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^5(i$+j)

From what I've gathered I should now expand the inner summation, and if I'm doing this correctly it should be like this:

(i+1) + (i+2) + (i+3) + (i+4) + (i+5)

And this leaves me with

$\sum_{i=2}^{10}(15 + 5i$)

Now I just want to make sure that I've been following the assignment correctly, and if so my next steps should be to do the following:

(15+10) + (15+15) + (15+20) + (15+25) + (15+30) + (15+35) + (15+40) + (15+45) + (15+50)

Which leaves me with 450 as the correct answer. But I'm not sure if I have been following the steps correctly here.

I did try [this website](https://rechneronline.de/sum/double-sum.php) to see if I came up with the same answer but that online calculator actually gave me 405 as the result which made me insecure about my own results and I wanted to see if anyone here could give me a nod in the right direction if I have made some mistakes along the way.

** EDIT ** For anyone looking into this question, I made a simple calculation error so the procedure that shows how the calculations are performed are correct, I just made a stupid error when putting the numbers correctly so the correct answer is 405, not 450 as I posted in this thread initially ****

Comment: Check your calculations. All your steps are correct until the evaluation of $(15+10) + (15+15) + \dots + (15+50)$

Comment: I did not check your actual arithmetic for the outer sum, but your procedure is correct.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I see the procedure was correct and that my mind was tricking me when doing the summation in my head. Stupid mistake but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is right until the summation:

$(15+10) + (15+15) + (15+20) + (15+25) + (15+30) + (15+35) + (15+40) + (15+45) + (15+50)=405$

But you can also use that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  k=n\cdot k$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c\cdot i=c\cdot \frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}$. Thus

$$\sum_{i=2}^{10}(15 + 5i)=\sum_{i=2}^{10} 15 + 5\cdot \sum_{i=2}^{10} i=(10-1)\cdot 15+5\cdot \left(\frac{10\cdot 11}{2}-1\right)$$ $$=9\cdot 15+5\cdot 54=135+270=405$$

Comment: Thank you, and since this sequence has a constant growth factor this makes it an arithmetic sequence - right?

Comment: You can say that $a_n=25+5\cdot n \ \forall n\in \mathbb N_0$ is an arithmetic sequence. These are the numbers $(15+10), (15+15), ...$ for $n=0,1,...$ But the sum is an arithmetic series.

Comment: Oh right, I mixed up the terminology, I'm studying discrete maths in a foreign language so I meant to say series, not sequence. Thanks again!

Comment: @lundzern That´s right. Check my comment again. I have made an edit. You´re welcome.